# Syntax Error (Missing Operator) when Updating Records using VB.net and MS Access

Tags: .net, ms-access

I want to update a record from my database. But when I click the update button, this always happen.

[image]
Here's my code.
Note that the data type of [Probationary_Date], [LeaveEffectivity], and [Promoted] is DATE/TIME..

```
Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click

        If btnEdit.Text = "EDIT" Then
            btnEdit.Text = "UPDATE"
            btnAdd.Enabled = False

            ACCOUNT_RECHECK()
            AdminValidation()
        Else
            If txtFname.Text = "" Or txtLname.Text = "" Or cmbType.Text = "" Or cmbGender.Text = "" Or txtSL.Text = "" Or txtVL.Text = "" Or cmbML.Text = "" Or txtPL.Text = "" Or txtSPL.Text = "" Or cmbVaw.Text = "" Or cmbSLFW.Text = "" Or txtSIL.Text = "" Or lblStatus.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("EMPTY FIELDS! ENTRY REQUIRED!")
                btnEdit.Text = "UPDATE"
                KondisyonOne()
            Else
                btnEdit.Text = "EDIT"
                btnAdd.Enabled = True
                TAGA_DISABLE()
                TAGA_DISABLEB()
                TAGA_DISABLEC()

                dbconnect.Open()
                qUpdate = "UPDATE Employee_Profile set Employee_Fname='" & txtFname.Text & "', Employee_Lname='" & txtLname.Text & "', Employee_Type='" & cmbType.Text & "', Employee_Gender='" & cmbGender.Text & "', SLTB='" & txtSL.Text & "', VLTB='" & txtVL.Text & "', MLS='" & cmbML.Text & "', PLTB='" & txtPL.Text & "', SPL='" & txtSPL.Text & "', VAWCLS='" & cmbVaw.Text & "', SLFWS='" & cmbSLFW.Text & "', SILTB='" & txtSIL.Text & "', LWPT='" & txtLWP.Text & "', Probationary_Date='" & DTProDate.Text & ", LeaveEffectivity='" & LeaveAvaiEffOn.Text & "', Promoted='" & PrmotedOn.Text & "', IsPromoted='" & cmbPromoted.Text & "', OldOrNew='" & cmbN_O.Text & "'where Employee_ID='" & Val(txtID.Text) & "'"
                dbcommand = New OleDbCommand(qUpdate, dbconnect)
                dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Updated!")
                dbconnect.Close()
                btnDelete.Enabled = False
                btnAdd.Enabled = True
                TAGA_CLEAR()
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

I hope you can help me with this! :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

String expressions for *Date* values must be wrapped in octothorpes like: `#2017-08-09#`

But do look up how to use *parameters* (many, many examples out there for the browsing).

That will be much easier for cases like this.

Comment: I already have an answer! :) Thanks for giving me an Idea! :)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.

Your argument string has a couple of typos.  There is no closing apostrophe for Probationary_Date, and you probably really should have a space between the final apostrophe and the WHERE clause of the SQL command.

Also, you should wrap the Date Values in Hashes/Octothorpes in #YYYY-MM-DD# format, rather than apostrophes.

Comment: I already have an answer! :) Thanks for giving me an Idea! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click



        If btnEdit.Text = "EDIT" Then
            btnEdit.Text = "UPDATE"

            btnAdd.Enabled = False

            ACCOUNT_RECHECK()
            AdminValidation()
        Else
            If txtFname.Text = "" Or txtLname.Text = "" Or cmbType.Text = "" Or cmbGender.Text = "" Or txtSL.Text = "" Or txtVL.Text = "" Or cmbML.Text = "" Or txtPL.Text = "" Or txtSPL.Text = "" Or cmbVaw.Text = "" Or cmbSLFW.Text = "" Or txtSIL.Text = "" Or lblStatus.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("EMPTY FIELDS! ENTRY REQUIRED!")
                btnEdit.Text = "UPDATE"
                KondisyonOne()
            Else

                btnEdit.Text = "EDIT"
                btnAdd.Enabled = True
                TAGA_DISABLE()
                TAGA_DISABLEB()
                TAGA_DISABLEC()

                dbconnect.Open()
                qUpdate = "UPDATE Employee_Profile set Employee_Fname='" & txtFname.Text & "', Employee_Lname='" & txtLname.Text & "', Employee_Type='" & cmbType.Text & "', Employee_Gender='" & cmbGender.Text & "', SLTB='" & txtSL.Text & "', VLTB='" & txtVL.Text & "', MLS='" & cmbML.Text & "', PLTB='" & txtPL.Text & "', SPL='" & txtSPL.Text & "', VAWCLS='" & cmbVaw.Text & "', SLFWS='" & cmbSLFW.Text & "', SILTB='" & txtSIL.Text & "', LWPT='" & txtLWP.Text & "', Probationary_Date=#" & DTProDate.Text & "#, LeaveEffectivity=#" & LeaveAvaiEffOn.Text & "#, Promoted=#" & PrmotedOn.Text & "#, IsPromoted='" & cmbPromoted.Text & "', OldOrNew='" & cmbN_O.Text & "' where Employee_ID=" & txtID.Text
                dbcommand = New OleDbCommand(qUpdate, dbconnect)
                dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Record Successfully Updated!")
                dbconnect.Close()
                btnDelete.Enabled = False
                btnAdd.Enabled = True
                TAGA_CLEAR()
                TAGA_REFRESH()




            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

This is the code I used. And it works :) Thank you guys! :)